# Backreference to matched attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

We can select elements based on [attribute matching](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp). Is there also a way to get a back-reference to the actual matched value? For example setting a background image based on the matched class:

```
div[class^="icon-"] {
    background-image: url(img/<reference here>.png);
}
```

Instead of manually specifying the path for each icon:

```
.icon-foo {
    background-image: url(img/icon-foo.png);
}

.icon-bar {
    background-image: url(img/icon-bar.png);
}

/* ... and so on ... */
```

Comment: No...there isn't

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay, maybe not pure CSS, but is there some CSS preprocessing engine that is capable of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: Sass mixin maybe but it will still churn out a shipload of CSS instead of you having to write it.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not possible with CSS only. But you could use JavaScript:

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="icon-"]');
for (icon of icons) {
 icon.style.backgroundImage = `url('img/${icon.classList}.png')`;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-home"></div>
<div class="icon-play"></div>
<div class="icon-search"></div>
```