# How can I alter many sibling elements with CSS on hover

Tags: html, css

In the example below when we hover any row from group 1, all group 1 rows change colour. I want to apply this same logic for `N` number of groups.

Let's say we have 300 of these groups of 3 rows. How can we achiveve this highlighting for each group without copy and pasting the CSS rule 300 times.

Can this be achieved with pure css?

```css
.parent:has(.group-1:hover) .group-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body class="parent">
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
</body>
```

Comment: sounds like you should rethink your HTML.... wrapping them in a common parent is your best bet

Comment: You have asked this a different way already in https://stackoverflow.com/q/77010481/125981 what differs here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I alter sibling element CSS on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010481/how-can-i-alter-sibling-element-css-on-hover)

Comment: Because it is a new question @MarkSchultheiss.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176649/backreference-to-matched-attribute

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The previous question only applies to two groups. This needs to apply to `N` number of groups.

Comment: If you want to have several hundred CSS rules you can do this I suppose... but keep in mind that [the `:has` pseudo-selector does not currently work in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-has).  A much better approach would be to structure your HTML differently or use some Javascript to select the related elements

Comment: @epascarello I'm working with absolute positioned cells within a virtualized table. Rethinking the HTML will be incredibly complex in this specific case

Comment: So your only real solution would be JavaScript if you can not alter the structure.

Comment: Yes if there's no pure CSS solution, I'll end up using JS here. Just wanted to check if there's anything I'm missing first

Comment: I thought there might be a solution somehow combining `:nth-child` with `:has` or something along those lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you can not alter the HTML to make them wrapped in groups, you can dynamically create your CSS so you are not manually writing out all the rules.

```js
// get all the elements with the group class
const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('p[class*="group-"]')

// get all the classNames from the elements
const allClassNames = Array.from(allElements).map(({
  className
}) => className);

// de-dupe
const groupings = new Set(allClassNames);

// build the selectors
const selectors = Array.from(groupings.values()).map(className => `.parent:has(.${className}:hover) .${className}`).join(",")

// your CSS you want to be in the rule
const theStyles = 'background-color: blue;'

// make a stylesheet
const styleEl = document.createElement("style");

// add it to the document
document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

//get the sheet
const styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;

//create the new rule
styleSheet.insertRule(`${selectors}{${theStyles}}`, 0);
```

```css
P {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very nice, and I've used `styleSheet.insertRule` for some cases myself, but more commonly now when I have a dynamically generated page I also dynamically generate the CSS to go with it.  I've also had stylesheet links such as `<link href="/app/userstyle/custom.css">` where "custom.css" was not a file, but was generated and streamed out from the server for per-user preferences.

Comment: This is a clever workaround. I hadn't considered this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely know that each group has exactly 3 entries you can use a combination of nth-child, before pseudo element (to hold the background) and z-index.

This snippet confines the hover to the first element in a group, but it appears to the user that they are hovering on the group in general as it is a before pseudo element on the first element that is overlaying the others in the group.

```html
<style>
  .parent {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .parent>p {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2) {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2)::before {
    content: '';
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vw;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover::before {
    background: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover~p:nth-child(3n-2) {
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover~p:nth-child(3n-2)+p,
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover~p:nth-child(3n-2)+p+p {
    z-index: 3;
    rbackground: white;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover~p:nth-child(3n-2)::before {
    z-index: -1;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover+p,
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-2):hover+p+p {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n-1),
  .parent>p:nth-child(3n) {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
    <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
    <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
    <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
    <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
    <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
    <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
    <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
    <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
    <p class="group-4">Group 4</p>
    <p class="group-4">Group 4</p>
    <p class="group-4">Group 4</p>
    <p class="group-5">Group 5</p>
    <p class="group-5">Group 5</p>
    <p class="group-5">Group 5</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Aside: whether you would actually want to do this in practice is another matter. While it does achieve the highlighting, it is IMO a bit hacky and I'd probably go for a bit of JS just to make it more obvious what is going on ie. simpler to maintain.

Comment: The 3 rows here is variable unfortunately, but this is a good answer given how I phrased the question regardless

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident that this cannot currently be done in just CSS however a simple JS solution might be to assign a common data-attribute to all members of the group. So that when you hover over one member of the group, all members get given a `data-active` attribute.

Your CSS can then say '*all items having [data-attr] look hovered*':

```
p[data-active] {background:blue;}
```

I'm not the best at JS so I'm sure this can be improved but it is small and doesn't require any changes to the html or any dynamic construction of the CSS.

Here's a demo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".parent p")
  .forEach(p => addListeners(p));

function addListeners(p){
  p.addEventListener("mouseover", select);
  p.addEventListener("mouseout", deselect);
}

function select(){
  document.querySelectorAll("p."+this.className)
    .forEach(p => p.setAttribute("data-active",""));
}

function deselect(){
  document.querySelectorAll("p."+this.className)
    .forEach(p => p.removeAttribute("data-active"));
}
```

```css
p {margin:0}
p[data-active] {
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-1">Group 1</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-2">Group 2</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
  <p class="group-3">Group 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can give all of them 1 more class name besides their specific class names.
and also if you can do this:

```
.parent > *{}
```

this selection, let you select all of the parent/body children.
you can also select all `<p></p>` element if you have use `<p></p>` tag just here.

Comment: "let you select all of the parent/body children" — That isn't what they want to do though. They are asking how to select all the element which have the same class name as the hovered element (for an arbitrary number of class names).

Comment: unsure how that actually answers the question.